# Is there a way to develop Angular 6 and AngularJS1.6 applications at same machine?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I try to find a way to develop both Angular 6 app and AngularJS 1.6 app at same machine.

Here are my situation. I need work on 2 projects, one is brand new one that will use Angular 6 and Angular material design. another project is an old project that I just took over and it's using AngularJS 1.6. Is that possible I can develop both apps on my work laptop or I have to use Virtual machine for one of the apps? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: So you've tried and had what problems exactly?

Comment: Use web components

Comment: Yes you can. You can even develop the same project with angularjs and angular together. You would have known that if you took a quick look at the documents. https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 1):

They are clearly different frameworks. You can probably go without issues on the same machine.

The trick if you get into trouble for some common node_modules dependencies, is to use local packages, not global ones. But this should already be the default behavior for the dependencies.

What would require a bit more careful setup is if you need to develop both on Angular 2 and Angular 7 for instance, if you installed some of the libraries globally (which is probably the case if you use angular-cli).

Even though, it's achievable anyway : https://blog.angularindepth.com/angular-5-or-angular-6-yes-please-d71b08b5e59b

Comment: I always only work on one angular app before, so my question is what the steps I should take to run 2 apps at same time, do I need uninstall all angular global packages and then install those packages locally within the app folders?

Comment: Pac0, I looked at that link. If I applied that method with Angular 6 and AngularJS, will that work? Like I install Angular-cli 1.6 for AngularJS.

Comment: @whwanthony Yes, if the Angular-cli package has the exact same name for AngularJs and Angular6, I think that would be basically the same solution.